# How to calculate distance traveled given constant acceleration and initial speed

Tags: performance, physics, acceleration

I have to do an animation, and I need a spinning wheel (constant speed), to start decelerating (constant acceleration) until it stops. I need to start the deceleration at the correct time so that the wheel stops exactly at a pre-determined position.
In other words, given an initial speed (for example, in pixels per second) and an acceleration value, I need to figure out the total distance travelled until the speed is 0.

Code can be any language, or pseudo-code, but preferably C.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try doing any math?

Comment: I did but I am unsure of my results... I think I missed something...

Comment: Can you show your results? Maybe we could point out what you missed.

Comment: a = A


v = At + Vs  —> gives velocity as a function of time, acceleration and start speed


p = At2 + Vst + Ps —> gives position as a function of time, acceleration, startSpeed and position


Solve first equation for v = 0 (to know when it stops)


At + Vs = 0


t = -Vs/A


distance:


At2+Vst = distance traveled —> substitute t=-Vs/A


Vs2/A - Vs2/A = ????

Comment: It seems like I get 0 at the end, which is obviously not correct...

Comment: For some reason I can't get line breaks to show above...

Comment: Comments are mostly for… comments. You can [edit] that information into your question with full formatting.

Comment: OK I found the answer here:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/stopping-distance-frictionless Basic answer is vˆ2/2a

Comment: Great! Can you implement that in C?

Comment: Yes. The implementation is easy, I just needed the formula. Thanks